# How to get route data from Identity Server 4 endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, datadog

I have a ResponseTimeMiddleware.cs responsible for getting response time metrics (I am using datadog) for every request made. Which is tagged by controller and action names. However when we hit the "connect/token" endpoint, the context.GetRouteData() is null, probably because identity server is doing it behind the scenes. Is there a way I could get this information or some other unique information where I could tag with?

here's my code:

```
public class ResponseTimeMiddleware
{

    // other code..

    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            watch.Stop();

            var routeData = context.GetRouteData();
            var responseTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            var tags = new[] { $"statusCode:{context.Response.StatusCode.ToString()}", $"controller:{routeData.Values["controller"]}", $"action:{routeData.Values["action"]}" };

            context.Response.Headers[ResponseHeaderResponseTime] = responseTime;

            DogStatsd.Timer("response.time", responseTime, tags: tags);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

        return nextDelegate(context);
    }
}
```

This is my Startup:

```
public class Startup
{

    // other code..

    public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseMiddleware<ResponseTimeMiddleware>();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseEndpointRouting();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseIdentityServer();

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public async void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDataDogStatsd(Configuration, "identity");

        // other code
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever been able to find an answer to this question? I am basically trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I did as @vidmantas-blazevicius suggested. Adding an if-else block:
`if (routeData != null)
{
 tags = tags.Concat(new[] { $"controller:{routeData.Values["controller"]}", $"action:{routeData.Values["action"]}" }).ToArray();
}
else if (context.Request.Path.HasValue)
{
 tags = tags.Concat(new[] { $"path:{context.Request.Path}" }).ToArray();
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `context.Request.Path` conditionally if your `routeData` is null. It is the closest I can think of since Identity Server 4 middleware has internal routing logic for the standard OAuth protocol routes.